# Saved image 'cannot be displayed because it contains errors'

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm saving images to my s3 bucket but although I see the files saved I can't open them. In firefox I get the error "image cannot be displayed because it contains erros". **This code worked** when saving images to the server so I just changed it to save accordingly to the bucket:

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'region' => $region,
    'version' => $version
));

$bucket = "test";
$file_path = $bucket . "/this/is_working/";

try {

    $content_type = "image/" . $extension;

    // Upload a file.
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'       => $bucket,
            'Key'          => $file_path,
            'ACL'          => 'public-read',
            'ContentType'  => $content_type,
            'Body'   => $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']
    ));
```

As I said, I do see the file with it's name .png but whenever I try to get the link `http://region.amazonaws.com/bucket/file` it fails with 'cannot be displayed because contains errors`. Any idea on this one? TYVM for your help...

Comment: it might be easier to diagnose if you link to one of the s3-linked images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you opened one of those images right now you would find it is a text file containing the name of the file you were trying to upload.

Try using     'SourceFile' instead of 'Body' in the putObject call:

```
   $result = $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'       => $bucket,
            'Key'          => $file_path,
            'ACL'          => 'public-read',
            'ContentType'  => $content_type,
            'SourceFile'   => $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']
    ));
```

Or open the file and stream the contents:

```
   $result = $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'       => $bucket,
            'Key'          => $file_path,
            'ACL'          => 'public-read',
            'ContentType'  => $content_type,
            'Body'   => fopen($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], 'r+')
    ));
```

The SDK documentation provides further examples http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject